# Trying to override the JUL logger used by vert.x

Tags: vert.x, vertx-verticle

I'd like to use Log4j2 and am setting up my MainVerticle with system properties to do that,

```
public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle
{
    static {
        System.setProperty( "vertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name",
                            "io.vertx.core.logging.Log4j2LogDelegateFactory" );
        System.setProperty( "log4j2.debug", "true" );
    }
....
}
```

I then deploy my HttpVerticle from this verticle, and in the HTTP verticle, I'm trying to use parameterized statements, which aren't working.  So I added a couple of logging statements to show the logger delegate in-use, as well as the system property:

```
public class HttpServerVerticle extends AbstractVerticle
{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger( HttpServerVerticle.class );

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception
    {
        LOGGER.info( System.getProperty( "vertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name" ) );
        LOGGER.info( LOGGER.getDelegate().getClass().getName() );
        ....
```

And below in a handler of the incoming message, I'm using this:

```
LOGGER.info( "Chat message received: {}" + message.body(), message.body() );
```

Note that I'm adding the message.body() using concatenation to prove that the message is not an empty string.

The output of these log statements are:

```
[INFO] Sep 24, 2018 2:46:09 AM ca.LinkEdTutoring.chat.http.HttpServerVerticle
[INFO] INFO: io.vertx.core.logging.Log4j2LogDelegateFactory
[INFO] Sep 24, 2018 2:46:09 AM ca.LinkEdTutoring.chat.http.HttpServerVerticle
[INFO] INFO: io.vertx.core.logging.JULLogDelegate
```

and for an incoming message of the letter "b":

```
[INFO] INFO: Chat message received: {}b
```

I've tried setting the system properties in the pom.xml file and on the command line with -D arguments.

This is with vert.x 3.5.3

Any thoughts on what I've forgotten to do?

================

EDIT:  capturing the salient points from the comment thread.

1. cannot set system properties in a verticle, because the vert.x JUL logger gets initiated before the main verticle.
2. cannot set ... in the pom.xml when running the code with the vertx plugin.  The mvn vertx plugin must get invoked after vertx is initialized.
3. only way it seems possible to override the JUL logger is the command line, using -D vargs.
4. do not forget that vargs are set before the -jar switch, i.e., $ java -Dx=y -jar jarname.jar

Comment: Very often setting system properties in code doesn't work because by the time the static code is executed, the logging system has already been initialized. Setting the system property with `-D` on startup works for me though.

Comment: java -jar chatsrv-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dvertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name=io.vertx.core.logging.Log4j2LogDelegateFactory -Dlog4j2.debug=true
Sep 25, 2018 12:51:14 AM ca.LinkEdTutoring.chat.MainVerticle

Comment: Sep 25, 2018 12:51:16 AM ca.LinkEdTutoring.chat.http.HttpServerVerticle
INFO: io.vertx.core.logging.Log4j2LogDelegateFactory
Sep 25, 2018 12:51:16 AM ca.LinkEdTutoring.chat.http.HttpServerVerticle
INFO: io.vertx.core.logging.JULLogDelegate

Sep 25, 2018 12:51:33 AM ca.LinkEdTutoring.chat.http.HttpServerVerticle
INFO: Chat message received: {}chat

Comment: I agree about the static block losing in a race condition to the core vertx initialization phase.  Good catch.  Unfortunately, same behaviour with the command line.

Comment: Realized my mistake with the cli invocation...I'm a newb...you need to specify the vargs BEFORE the -jar switch.  It is now working.

Comment: BTW...for those in the same situation as I was, using $ mvn vertx:run does not allow you to set system properties in the pom.xml for overriding the JUL.  Seems the only way to override logging behaviour is the command line switch, after packaging the jar.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the command line to start, you can configure it with `-Dvertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name=io.vertx.core.logging.Log4j2LogDelegateFactory`. This is the easiest.

Of course, you can also set it directly in the code via System.setProperty, which is the same as the -D setting, but this must be done before the LoggerFactory is initialized. Obviously your code in the Verticle subclass must be executed after the Vertx initialization is successful. The LoggerFactory has already been initialized.